# In Lodash (JavaScript), is there a function to return the first "truthy" or "meaningful" value?

Tags: javascript, lodash

In Lodash, is there a way to do something like:

```
foo = firstTruthy(foo, bar, 10);
```

so that the first "truthy" value is assigned to `foo`?  The "truthy" is quoted because some values, such as `0` or `""` would like to be considered to be truthy.

---

Background info: in JavaScript, if we do

```
foo = foo || 10;
```

so that if `foo` is undefined, then it is set to `0`, but then there is a catch: if `foo` is `0`, it is also treated as falsy and therefore `foo` is assigned 10.  In Lodash or generic JavaScript, is there a way to do something like

```
foo = firstTruthy(foo, 10);         // this
foo = firstTruthy(foo, bar, 10);    // or this
```

so that the first truthy value is assigned to `foo`, where truthy is considered to be: everything not `false`, `null`, or `undefined`? (so even `0` or `""` is considered to be truthy, similar to Ruby).

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing the term "truthy" if you don't want `a = b || c`. "Truthy" values are well defined, and you can't arbitrarily include other values in that definition like `0` or `""`.

If you want to write your own "assign the value which is either truthy or zero or some other combination of conditions", use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var value = [foo, bar, baz].find(x => x || x == 0 || x == "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function firstTruthy(...args) {
    return args.find(arg => arg !== null && arg !== undefined && arg !== false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the values for truthyness or check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const firstTruthy = (...array) => array.find(a => a || [0, ''].includes(a));

console.log(firstTruthy(undefined, null, 10)); // 10
console.log(firstTruthy(undefined, 0, 10));    // 0
console.log(firstTruthy(false, '', 10));       // ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the term "truthy" when not speaking about Javascript's very specific definition of what is "truthy".
What you're asking for is something I use to refer to as *something* vs *nothing*. AFAIK Lodash doesn't have such a function. Here's my go-to solution for it:

```
/**
 * Return the first provided value that is something, or undefined if no value is something.
 * undefined, null and NaN are not something
 * All truthy values + false, 0 and "" are something
 * @param {*} values Values in order of priority
 * @returns {*} The first value that is something, undefined if no value is something
 */
function getSomething(...values) {
  return values.find(val => val !== null && val !== undefined && !Number.isNaN(val));
}
```

The difference here from what you're asking for is that my function considers `false` to be *something*. That's easily adjusted for.

Comment: yes, "something" or "hasMeaning"... if someone's bank account has $1 dollar, then it is true, then having $0 shouldn't be false because it is valid account value. Likewise for string search, if the search key is found at position 0, then it is also found, same as 1 or 20.